# Electron key board shortcuts

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

This is my code:

```
globalShortcut.register('Control+1',() => {
        console.log(win.isMaximized)
        win.isMaximized() ? win.unaximize() : win.maximize()
    })
```

My output  window is not maximized at the start. whenever I click control +1 , the window maximizes. but second time when I click, it is not minimizing as written in code.

can someone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo `win.unaximize()` isn't a method should be `win.unmaximize()`

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I tried after correcting it. Still not working, any help?

Comment: What platform are you running it on?

Comment: I installed electron globally through npm - Node JS . And I am using visual studio code.

Comment: I meant Windows/Linux/Mac, assuming it's Windows based on that answer. Seems to be a bug in Electron see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9092

Comment: My machine is Win 10. Thanks for help.